# Open a specific directory using Ulauncher

Tags: 20.04, launcher, search

I use Ulauncher in order to open apps from my keyboard.

I have set correctly the Ulauncher for IntelliJ & AndroidStudio as you can see in the picture below.

The point is that I would like to add a third option.

This option has to be a directory I daily use.

I have added the **ulauncher-file-search** extension by means of the installation (adding https://github.com/brpaz/ulauncher-file-search) to the extensions menu.

Any help to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance !!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You enter file browse mode by typing in a valid path directly as a ulauncher query. Ex: `~` or `/`.

Once you browse to a folder you can open the files in it with Ulauncher and the default application will open it. You can also press alt + enter to show more options, including opening a folder in your default file manager.

In the future we will probably add the ability to launch ulauncher and set the query (text) from a command so you can bind that to a keyboard command for example, but if all you want to do in the end is open a folder, you might not need Ulauncher. Your file manager probably has functionality to "pin" or create a shortcut for a folders you open often to the sidebar.